# How to select random data for two different recommender systems?

Tags: dataset, statistics, recommender-system, ab-test

The business problem: We have two different vendors that offer personalized recommender engines and want to do A/B testing with them. The recommendation will give the user a personalized offer via a push message on the phone. During the testing period, we should give each provider a dataset with different details regarding the customers (purchase history, in-app events, etc). Each vendor will receive a dataset with identical info but from different clients.

What is the best method to choose the two datasets so that they would be similar in terms of client behaviour?

I assume that giving them random data from our database wouldn't be a rigorous method so one idea that I have in mind is applying dbScan clustering on our database and further randomly picking clients from each cluster - I don't know if this is the best approach. The full database has 200k clients and each dataset should contain 5k clients.

Example: After dbScan clustering there are `k=10` clusters so I randomly pick elements from each cluster and split them into Dataset01 and Dataset02.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome @Remus Raphael :) - Your approach is a sound option.

More specifically, if a density-based algorithm was already working for you, I'd recommend the [HDBSCAN](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) clustering algo, which should have a better performance and has a unique built-in cluster validation (based on the [DBCV](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=dbcv) algorithm).

Then your general pipe line could be:

1. An optional pre-processing
2. An optional NLP / TFIDF for meaningful text features
3. An optional dimensionality reduction (I found [TSNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) and [TruncatedSVD](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) to
   work nicely with HDBSCAN with textual processing)
4. HDBSCAN tuning for different params and distance metrics
5. Finally, when you're satisfied with the clustering quality - you can simply start with the 2 largest clusters for your AB testing

I'd love to hear you feedback on your actual data :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very detailed explanation! Do you think it would be best to 1) choose sample data from the 2 largest clusters OR 2) include data from each cluster to have diversity and equally put it in the 2 testing Groups?

Comment: Assuming your measure of success is client actual purchases or PPC/PPV. I assume the whole purpose of clustering is to try and make sure each vendor gets a different client segment (so you can measure their success?) - If so then stick with original plan. If not, and you have another way of tracking back a success to a vendor, then why not send them both the top N clusters and let them compete? (like kaggle.com does). BTW, why sampling? is there a limitation of dataset size from the vendors' side?

Comment: We have a limitation on the dataset size from our side. We will send personalized push notifications. The goal is to have 2 different client groups that are similar in terms of profile, past transactions but also covers client diversity (low income, high income, high-frequent, low-frequent etc.) -> Maybe weighted clustering would be a solution.

Comment: I see, in that case then **sample all N** clusters and randomly split it between the 2 vendors. Then, track measure of success on your side (which provider's ad was pushed and was successful). You can set the `min_cluster_size` threshold to the size of those diverse groups your interested with, and then sampling all clusters should do the job for you (auto weighted for you). [min_cluster_size](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter_selection.html#selecting-min-cluster-size)

Comment: Your'e welcome and good-luck :) If you find this answer helpful please consider accepting it later